# I cannot insert select with HTML from Material CSS

Tags: html, css, node.js, materialize

I'm using Material CSS from https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css and trying to add something to html file.

I tried to input card and checkbox, button and it worked well

But I cannot add select button to my page. I just copied HTML from https://materializecss.com/select.html .

I can add Browser default select but cannot add any of others.

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
    <select multiple>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <label>Materialize Multiple Select</label>
  </div>
  <label>Browser Select</label>
  <select class="browser-default">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  </select>
```

This is my code and the result should be like this.

[image]

But the result is like this.

[image]

I don't know why I cannot add multiple selection and why two selection is placed on same location so people cannot read it well.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Did you do the jQuery initialization specified in the docs? It's specified at the  https://materializecss.com/select.html

Comment: Hi ozgur. Thanks for reply. You mean that $(document)~ code. right?

Comment: I already added it in HTML with the code <script> and </script> but still it doesn't work..

Comment: You have two select elements which may be breaking the code. Did you check your console for errors? Did you try with only 1 select? I also see that your second select is not wrapped in a div with appropriate class names

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just copied the same script from that webpage but I should change "option" value to name of div class.("input-field col s12")

Comment: Then it's working perfect now. Thank you for reply.

Comment: I'm glad it resolved your issue